# Match files which contain all specified words in notepad++ "find in files", regardless of order

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a list of words:

- Alpha
- Beta
- Charlie
- Delta
- Echo

And a list of 1000 multi-line files. One or more of these files contains all 5 of the words, the others contain 4 or fewer. The words can appear in the files in any order. However, each word only appears once in each file.

I need to find the one or more files which contain all 5 words.

I am trying lots of regex to plug into "find in files" in notepad++ but I cannot make it work. Trying for one hour now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A(?=.*\bAlpha\b)(?=.*\bBeta\b)(?=.*\bCharlie\b)(?=.*\bDelta\b)(?=.*\bEcho\b)`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A                      # beginning of file
(?=                     # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*                      # 0 or more any character
    \b                      # word boundary
    Alpha                   # word to search
    \b                      # word boundary
)                       # end lookahead
(?=.*\bBeta\b)          # same for 2nd word
(?=.*\bCharlie\b)       # same for 3rd word
(?=.*\bDelta\b)         # ...
(?=.*\bEcho\b)          # ...
```

This makes sure we have **all** the 5 words in **any order** in the files.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Awesome that works thank you!!

Comment: @tomredfern: You're welcome, glad it helps.